# Make labels in the composer view exactly the same size as in layout view

Tags: qgis, print-composer

I currently struggle to get the labels in the composer and the layout view to have the exact same size and beeing at the same position. I need to know that in order to manually place overlapping labels.

this is how it looks like in the layout view:

[image: Layout view]

this is how it looks like in the composer view, having set the reference scale to exactly the same as the layout scale:

[image: Magnification 200%]

If I set the reference scale of the layers to double the layout scale and zoom in a couple of percent, it seems to almost match.

[image]

Any help on that? I red that I could transform the font size to map units, but I wouldn't like to do that because it should match with other text.

related threads:

- [Showing labels as they will be printed/exported in my print layout?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/346200/showing-labels-as-they-will-be-printed-exported-in-my-print-layout?rq=1)
- [Why are font and line sizes different in QGIS's Print Composer and how do I normalize them?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/74281/why-are-font-and-line-sizes-different-in-qgiss-print-composer-and-how-do-i-norm)